# Visual Studio Code Key Bindings From Search

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am getting an error with key bindings when I search within a VS Code (command F on Mac) notebook. When I hit enter the cursor remains in the search bar & text is highlighted. If I wanted to clear the search bar and hit 'delete' (backspace equiv), I get a chord message '(Backspace) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord.." [image: see this screenshot]

However, if I look into keyboard shortcuts I find I actually do not have ones that begin with that key. Here is the screenshot of keyboard shortcuts with 'recording' turned on to get all that start with 'delete' [image: recording screenshot]

Anyone know what is going on here or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After pressing Ctrl+Shift+P, search for `Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting`. This will log you the keyboard events. You may for example be pressing Backspace without Ctrl being up again, and this logs will show you the keybindings that caused this chord message.

After finding the keys that caused the chord, go to settings and find the other bindings.

If you can't find it, you may try going to a random command, double click it and press on the keys that you found as the cause of the chord. VS Code will tell you the other commands with the same key bindings, at the bottom of input pop-up. Click on it and find the other binding.

If these still don't work, an extension that you installed may cause this problem, but I don't know the solution in that case.